# Second Derivative Chain Rule

Tags: calculus

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. I'd like to find $D^2(F\circ\varphi)$.

$(D(F\circ\varphi))_t=(DF)_{\varphi(t)}\circ (D\varphi)_t$.

I'm a little confused as to how you would proceed to find the derivative of $D(F\circ\varphi)$. You'd want to think of $ D(F\circ\varphi)$ without the $t$ dependence,so $D(F\circ\varphi)=(DF)_{\varphi}\circ DF$. So then applying the chain rule again, $(D^2(F\circ\varphi))_t=(D(DF\circ\varphi))_{(DF)_t}\circ (D^2F)_t$. This doesn't seem right to me. Can anyone explain?

Comment: maybe related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407699/expansion-of-some-operators-in-a-second-total-derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the derivative of $G=F∘φ$ is a product $G'=(F'∘φ)\cdot φ'$, you have to use the product rule for the second derivative,
$$
G''=(F''∘φ)[φ',φ']+(F'∘φ)\cdot φ''.
$$
Note that as linear algebra object, $F''$ is a third order tensor, or a vector valued symmetric bilinear form.

Comment: Why is $G'$ a product $G'=(F'\circ\varphi)\cdot\varphi'$, instead of a composition $G'=(F'\circ\varphi)\circ\varphi'$?

Comment: In the same sense that matrix multiplication is. The composition of $S(x)=Ax$ and $T(y)=By$ is given by the matrix product, $(T∘S)(x)=BAx$. The different terms essentially serve to distinguish the specific composition of linear operators as "multiplication" from the general composition of non-linear maps.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Thank you!